Difference between factor and category in R
In the Hmisc::describe documentation (at page 76) there is written:

This function determines whether the variable is character, factor, category, binary, discrete numeric, and continuous numeric, and prints a concise statistical summary according to each

What is the difference between a "factor" and a "category"?

On page 12 of the same document, it is stated that:

Categorical predictors are required to be coded as integers (as factor
does internally).

So the difference is mainly their appearance if I get it right.

Seems right ... Hmisc::describe(factor(c("a", "a", "c", "b"), levels = letters[1:5])) gives similar output to Hmisc::describe(c(1,1,3,2)). So it treats integer vectors similarly to factors
